# VB.NET 2010 command line program needs file to be in same directory?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a noob at this and was wondering if someone might be able to help.

I'm putting together a frontend in Visual Basic (VS2010 version) for a cd recording command line program called cdrdao.

Here's the link for a win32 version. http://www.student.tugraz.at/thomas.plank/
The version of cdrdao posted there depends on two dll files. cygwin1.dll, and cyggcc_s-sjlj-1.dll.
I have the three files in my bin/debug directory.

Here's my code

```
Private Sub btnOpen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
    Dim myfile As String
    myfile = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    myfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    lblFile.Text = myfile
End Sub

Private Sub btnBurn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBurn.Click
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim p As New Process
    strFile = lblFile.Text
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cdrdao.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = " simulate " + strFile
    p.Start()
    MessageBox.Show(p.StartInfo.Arguments.ToString(), "result")

End Sub
```

When I run this, it wont receive the strFile. The strFile is the image.cue

It shows that it does in my messagebox, but it just wont work.

If my strFile(imagefile) is in the same directory as my exe, and cdrdao which is in bin/debug and I set these arguments, and click btnBurn.

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " simulate " + "myimage.cue"
```

Then it works as expected.

Here's a scenario that works when I start a command prompt.

I have a folder on my desktop named test, and it contains cdrdao, and the dlls.
I have a folder on G: drive called test, and it contains the image file to be burned.

I type this into the cmd.

```
cd /d G:\test
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test\cdrdao simulate  G:\test\myimage.cue
```

This works too.

I was wondering if anyone might have any clues on how I can get this working? Is it a directory problem? Any help would greatly appeciated.

Comment: but you are telling us that this is clearly a folder problem.. p needs to know the path of the thing is using (unless they are clearly on a default folder).

Comment: @ gbianchi Thanks for the quick responce. Sorry for being such a noob. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cdrdao.exe"
```

Should include the path to the program.

strFile should include the path too.

Comment: @ gbianchi The strFile shows the correct path in my messagebox, and I tried this: p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\Wyatt\Desktop\cdrdao\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\cdrdao.exe" I wish I could figure it out.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?  The app may not have sufficient rights to read or execute it.

Comment: The strFile works if its in the same dir as the application, but not a different location.

Comment: @Wyatt- This contradicts your own example of exe on desktop and file in G:\Test

Comment: Thanks for all the replys. I just can't get it to work. My son and I have sucessfully used the same code above with another command program called cdrecord, and it works. cdrdao likes to see the image file in the same dir. I just cant figure it out. Any more ideals?

Comment: gbianchi was right. It worked by using ChDir.             directoryName = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFile)
ChDir(directoryName)